# best / easiest way to turn an excel spreadsheet into a queryable database

Tags: database, excel

I have all this info from a big spreadsheet of customers looking for a product that I sell.  I sell about 20 different products.  When I have one single product to sell I want to query the spreadsheet/database and send an email to all the customers who may be interested in the product that I want to sell.  It would be nice to have a checklist that identifies the exact customers that i should contact about my product for sale.

The checklist would be similar to an advanced search on eBay when you are looking for a precise product and then it returns say 20 or so results.  Those results for me would be the customers that I could sell to.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the checklist bit?

Comment: Assuming that the data in the spreadsheet is going to change as time goes on, you need to consider whether you will update the database directly or whether you will update the spreadsheet then use the spreadsheet to update the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're question isn't entirely clear. It's also not very clear how this data is stored.

The *easiest* way to do this would be to just use an Excel filter.

If you actually want to turn this into a database, what kind of database? SQL Server Integration Services has a [fantastic tool](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205) for importing an excel file into a db table, which you could then query. If you want to use access, [this is](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/techniques-for-successfully-importing-excel-data-into-access/5276622) one method.

What are you going for?

Comment: I am in a managed assets dept at a bank.  We have a long long list of customers looking to buy distressed loans (loans are backed up by many different types of collateral).  In our long list of customers they are all looking for different types of loans and collateral.  My goal is to create a database in hopes to contact certain customers if I need to liquidate a loan asap.  Kinda just scratchin the surface in hopes to be short.

Comment: You are dealing with real money at a bank, and they don't have a system for this? That scares me a little. I would recommend the SQL route, but it's got a learning curve that you should be prepared for. I really don't think someone who is learning should be handling money for a bank.

Comment: don't worry theres no money in this transaction. We're just looking for a more efficient way to contact certain customers when need be...whats the best way to set up the sql route? Should i attempt to export the excel file to access? or some other way?...thanks for help

Comment: If you don't have SQL, SSIS does not come with the free version. You would have to purchase it, and its not cheap. If you already have Access (comes with Office, usually) that will be the cheaper route. The second link I posted has a good tutorial of the process you will have to go through.